# Optimising objects and data structure

Tags: jquery, html, json

Looking to clarify my understanding of JavaScript objects, JSON and efficiency. please take a look at the examples below. If the data sets were much bigger with thousands of objects, I understand approach three to be the most efficient and the right choice for three reasons:

1. Unlike approach two, there is no loop - it doesn't run through the whole dataset. The chosen object is referenced directly by name.
2. Unlike approach one, there is no need to eval() the selection in order to reference it. Once less step.
3. The use of JSON in both approaches two and three are preferable to the separate objects in approach one. The JSON is more 'packaged' and transferable.

**The goal is to have a large data set which includes thousands of objects, each with ~15 properties (mainly numbers). The property data will be accessed using various HTML form selections and then the numerical properties run through various calculations in javascript. Before I start building the dataset, I'm just thinking through its structure.**

Specific Questions (for the goal scenario described):
Does the loop in option 2 cause any inefficiency versus referencing an object by its name like in approaches 1 and 3?
With the large dataset described, does the eval function in approach 1 cause any real inefficiency?
By inefficiency - I mean noticeable load time of a website.

HTML:

```
<select id="increment">
    <option value="one">Increment One</option>
    <option value="two">Increment Two</option>
</select>
```

Approach one:

```
var one = {"count":0,"desc":"blah"};
var two = {"count":0,"desc":"blah"};


$("#increment").change(function(){
choice = $( "#increment option:selected" ).val();
a = eval(choice);
a.count++;
});
```

Approach two:

```
var options = [{ "name":"one","count":0,"desc":"blah"},{"name":"two","count":0,"desc":"blah"}]

$("#increment").change(function(){
    choice = $( "#increment option:selected" ).val();
    for (i = 0; i < options.length; i++) { 
       if(options[i].name == choice){options[i].count++}
    }
});
```

Approach three:

```
var options = {
    "one":{"count":0,"desc":"blah"},
    "two":{"count":0,"desc":"blah"}
}

$("#increment").change(function(){
    choice = $( "#increment option:selected" ).val();
    options[choice].count++;
});
```

Comment: You've described your approaches and supplied the code, but you did not explain what exactly you are trying to achieve and what your goal is with your code. Please explain that.

Comment: This question is too broad.  The structure in which you should make your data model depends highly upon the data, and how your application will use it.  Both of those things are very situational.

Comment: added some clarity to my goal

Comment: Your goal is still a generalization, and is still too broad.